# How to get songs from album/Artist in android,using MediametadataRetriever?

Tags: android, media

First of all i am a newbie and secondly i know there exists a solution for "How to get songs from album  in android?" but that is by using cursor and MediaStore and i have used MediametadataRetriever and its totally different  i haven't used hashmaps and all.....so its getting a bit difficult....please any solutions for this???without using hashmaps and mediastore???

here is the code i have used to display all songs and its artists ..........

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class FragmentSongs extends  Fragment implements Serializable {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_song, container, false);
        ListView SngList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.SongList);
        registerForContextMenu(SngList);
        File f=new File("/sdcard/Music");
        int j=0;int i=0;
        final ArrayList<SongDetails> Songinfo = getSongsFromDirectory(f);

        if (Songinfo.size()>0) {
            for( j=0; j<Songinfo.size();j++) {
                for ( i=j+1 ; i<Songinfo.size(); i++) { 
                    SongDetails a=Songinfo.get(i);
                    SongDetails b=Songinfo.get(j);
                    if (a.getSong().toLowerCase().compareTo(b.getSong().toLowerCase()) < 0) {
                        Songinfo.set(i,b );
                        Songinfo.set(j,a);
                    }
                 }
             }

             SngList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 
                 public void onItemClick(AdapterView a, View v, int position, long id) {
                     Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NowPlaying.class);
                     intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("Data1",Songinfo);

                     intent.putExtra("Data2",position);
                     startActivity(intent);
                 }
             });

             SngList.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(Songinfo));
             return view;
         } else {
             return null;
         }
   }

   public ArrayList<SongDetails> getSongsFromDirectory(File f) {
       MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
       ArrayList<SongDetails> songs = new ArrayList<SongDetails>();
       Bitmap bitmap2; 
       Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ab);

       float ht_px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 100, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
       float wt_px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 100, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

       Bitmap bitmap3 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, (int) ht_px, (int) wt_px, true);
       byte[] rawArt = null;
       Bitmap art;
       BitmapFactory.Options bfo=new BitmapFactory.Options();
       if (!f.exists() || !f.isDirectory()) {    
           return songs;
       }
       File[] files = f.listFiles(new Mp3Filter());
       for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++) { 
           if (files[i].isFile()) { 
               mmr.setDataSource(files[i].getPath());
               rawArt = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();
               SongDetails detail=new SongDetails(); 
               if ( rawArt != null) {
                   bitmap2=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(rawArt, 0, rawArt.length, bfo);
                   bitmap2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap2, (int) ht_px, (int) wt_px, true);
                   detail.setIcon(bitmap2);
               } else {  
                   detail.setIcon(bitmap3);
               }

               detail.setSong(files[i].getName()); 
               detail.setArtist(files[i].getName());
               detail.setArtist( mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST)); 
               detail.setAlbum( mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM)); 
               detail.setPath2( files[i].getPath()) ;
               songs.add(detail); 
            } else if (files[i].isDirectory()) { 
                songs.addAll(getSongsFromDirectory(files[i])); 
            } 

        }
        return songs;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);      
        info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, v.getId(), 0, "Play");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, v.getId(), 0, "Delete");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, v.getId(), 0, "Queue Item");                  
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getTitle() == "Play") {

        } else if (item.getTitle() == "Delete") {

        } else if (item.getTitle() == "Queue Item") {

        } else {
            return false;
        }
            return true;
    }
}

class Mp3Filter implements FileFilter {
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        return (file.isDirectory()||file.getName().endsWith(".mp3")|| file.getName().endsWith(".Mp3"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do clean up the line breaks, indentation and {} of your code. Currently it is very hard to read. Please also indicate where in the code you problem is.

Comment: Well there is no problem in the code......i have posted this code for those who say "where is the code you are using"what i am doing is i am searching for all the files and then displaying the songs and their respective album art , artist and albums in a custom list..there has been no problem till now...the code works fine....but i don't know how to display all songs from a particular artist or an album.....i don't want to be using string sorting and all because it will make my code very heavy ....

Comment: So if there are no problems with code, check available [examples](http://www.androidadb.com/class/me/MediaMetadataRetriever.html) and use them to create what you want.

Comment: Well can you provide me with any such example?

Answer (score 7):

Check out this tutorial:

http://www.srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/android/audioplayer.aspx

You can modify it slightly to suit your needs:

```
private ArrayList<SongDeatils> getSongList(File musicFolder) {
    ArrayList<SongDeatils> songs = new ArrayList<SongDeatils>();

    for (File f : musicFolder.listFiles()) {
        MediaMetadataRetriever md = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        md.setDataSource(musicFolder + "/" + f.getName());

        // Assign variables like title, artist, etc

        SongDeatils s = new SongDeatils();
        s.setTitle(title);
        s.setArtist(artist);
        s.setSong(f.getPath());
        // ...

        songs.add(s);
    }     

    return songs;
}
```

For image (cover art) handling, it should really be done asynchronously in the adapter. I'd suggest using [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).

**Update:**

Just saw your comments. What you really want is an efficient way to list songs from a specific album or artist, without using file filters and sorting. The only other option, then, is to use `MediaStore`/`Cursor`. There are different types of queries that you can construct, depending on how you are trying to view the data.

So, to query for a list of artist, you would use `MediaStore.Audio.Artists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` and use the artist name as your selection args.

For a list of albums, you now have the `ARTIST_KEY` which you can use to query `MediaStore.Audio.Artists.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`, to obtain a list of albums for the given artist.

For an example of how to list all albums for a given artist, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9538189/377260).

Comment: thanx but I don't want to use MediaStore , i  already mentioned that.Is there any way i can use Mediametadataretriever to get the desired results?

Comment: Yes, I gave an example and a link. You have 2 options: use Files and manage the sorting/filtering yourself, or use MediaStore. There are no other options.

Comment: Well in the given e.g filtering is not implemented

Comment: But i guess i have to do that myself

Comment: Yeah, if you must use Files, you will have to take care of all of that sorting/filtering yourself. Could you explain the reason why you can't, or won't, use the `MediaStore`?

Comment: Lol because i took so much time developing my own code ,using metadata ("given  above ")and now if i use mediastore ,it will simply go in vain.

Comment: i have one more question ....the code is taking too much time to load.....what can i do to make it faster??should i save the results in an another file and fetch the list from there ?or am i doing something really stupid in this code(which is making it slower)?

Comment: and one more question if you would like to answer ...is parsing xml easier than json?
is it worth it to convert a json file into xml and then parse xml out of it?(because i find parsing xml easier )

Comment: *"Lol because i took so much time developing my own code"* -- Worst reason, ever! In time, you'll get used to scrapping large pieces of code. Eventually, it feels good. *"The code is taking too much time to load"* -- Using MediaStore/Cursors is much, much faster. Much... Faster. *"is parsing xml easier than json"* -- No, but Android has heavily optimized XML parsers (SAXParser, XMLPullParser). Definitely not worth converting json to xml. Check out Gson.

Comment: Well the time issue is resolved if i don't generate the bitmaps....turn's out there  wasn't an issue with metadata

Comment: and thanx for suggesting me  Universal Image Loader.

Comment: Glad it's working. Please accept this answer if the issue is resolved.

Comment: What is the outstanding problem? I went to great lengths to answer all of your questions and provide all options available. I believe I've earned the bounty.

Comment: Well you have told me that for getting songs from an album/artist i will have to use mediastore...something which i already knew (according to my question's description-"......i know there exists a solution for "How to get songs from album in android?" but that is by using cursor and MediaStore.........." but if you still think you   deserve to get the bounty i will give it to you..

Comment: well since there are no other options ...either i have to use mediastore or develop my own code....i think u deserve the bounty,sorry if i had been rude earlier

Comment: but i haven't accepted your answer...when i will develop my own code ...i will post it here and accept it

Answer (score 0):

@Anknit Mediastore do not detect the all directories in your device. 
I no it scans very much faster than what we try to build our own code. 
But it do no detect some folder. Today I am creating my project in my phone I have  directories namely **.trash-100 & .trash** it contains almost .mp3 files. 
It were not detected by even the VLC and by default music player except the Poweramp.
Please refer the following link
http://mrbool.com/how-to-extract-meta-data-from-media-file-in-android/28130
I just used recursion for that and it worked fine